# Getting error from ArcGIS Field calculator with vbScript?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, field-calculator, vbscript

I am trying to do the following in the field calculator in ArcGIS 10

```
if  [IncdStDir] = " " then [IncdStNo] &" " & [IncdStName] &" " & [IncdStSfx]

else  [IncdStNo] &" " & [IncdStDir]&" " & [IncdStName] &" " & [IncdStSfx]

end if
```

I keep getting an error when I try to run this. I am new to Vb.

Comment: What is the error message you're getting in the Geoprocessing-Results window?

Answer (score 1):

**Updated code as @Russell Mercer suggested.**

Make sure you have the advanced checkbox checked and are calculating on the field you want the result posted to.   Try this:

```
Dim output

if  [IncdStDir] = " " then
output = [IncdStNo] & " " & [IncdStName] & " " & [IncdStSfx]

else 

output = [IncdStNo] & " " & [IncdStDir] & " " & [IncdStName] & " " & [IncdStSfx]

end if
```

And include **output** variable in the Prelogic section.

Comment: That did not work. I put the Dimo output as string in the Pre-logic section and then I copied your text in to the other section. Do I also have to put the Dim part in there as well?

Comment: The parser in ArcMap is a little quirky at times. Try adding a space after all ampersands (so, `& " "` instead of `&" "`) to see if that helps. As long as all of those columns actually exist in the layer, nothing else looks wrong.

Comment: I have tried that and that did not work.

Comment: @alicia Have you looked at the error message in Results? That might provide a hint in the right direction.

Comment: The errors that I get are Error999999, Expected end of statement and Failed to execute. And a warning that says General error executing calculator.

Comment: @alicia - I just read today something about declaring variables using VBScript in ArcGIS 10.  Variables are all declared as variant, so declaring a variable as
    "Dim output as string"
will throw an error.  The recommendation from the ESRI moderator was to change that to
    "Dim output"
I don't have confirmation that this works, but your error matches the error others were reporting for the same circumstance.

Answer (score 1):

Your Else clause doesn't have an = sign. You're not setting anything there, just concatenating fields. You need to set a value, call a function, or do something (technically you could leave the else clause blank, but that would be pointless). Just concatenating fields without setting a variable to them isn't a valid statement within the clause.

Comment: and by "= sign" you mean an *assignment* operator (as VB has overloaded this operator with *[equality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equality_(relational_operator)#Confusion_with_assignment_operators)*)

Answer (score 1):

You said you "put the Dimo output as string in the Pre-logic section and then I copied your text in to the other section". This is not correct for the field calculator.

Paste all of the code from "*Dim output*..." to "...*End If*" in the **Pre-logic** section. The only text in the other section should be **output**.